# Disable jenkins replay

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using a shared library. Wanted to know of any options by which I can disable the replay option in pipeline jobs. I find that to be a major drawback of using pipeline jobs as its easy to manipulate the groovy scripts in a replay.

Comment: As for Q4 2020 there is no such ability
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39874